# $content_width for responsive UI

Tags: responsive, user-interface, content-width

In our "*mobile first*" age a theme without responsive UI is treated like from stone age. It means that a theme could have different content width for different devices. But one of requirements for theme development is to provide [`$content_width`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) variable which should contain actual width of content area of a theme.

Taking in consideration said above, I have the big question what width should I set for `$content_width` variable? A width for `mobile phones`/`tables`/`laptops`/`desktops`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When that variable was added to themes, was the [July 2008](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.6). First time someone start talk about responsive design was the [May 2010](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), two years later.

Nowadays, that variable have lost is important (if ever it had one).

Codex itself recommend to set the max width in css, like

```
.size-auto, 
.size-full,
.size-large,
.size-medium,
.size-thumbnail {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

and we know that it can be made *responsive* using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

This is sufficient to avoid content break layout in modern themes.

However, the `$content_width` variable, is referred to max width that the theme handle, not the max width that the client device can visualise.

So if your theme as a fixed layout, where the main column is large, e.g. 600px, set `$content_width` to that value.

If you have a flexible layout, or a responsive one, just set the recommended css and don't use `$content_width` at all or set it to a *reasonable* big size (full hd?), because it is the **biggest** size you want to display, and if the client device don't support that width you have to accomplish in other ways, sure not decreasing that value..

Comment: This rule should be extended by `.entry iframe` or alike as (of WP 4.6) it doesn't affect video iframes like when embedding YouTube.

Comment: It's a shame themeForest still demands on this value to be set. It's ruining my design, since my theme behaves differently on screen sizes above 1920 px wide.